# the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, file-upload, process, dispose

```
public ActionResult _Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file, GaleriesViewModel galeriesViewModel)
{
    Images image = new Images();

    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        try
        {
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Galeries/Galery_" + galeriesViewModel.sno), fileName);
            var smallImagePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Galeries/Small/Galery_" + galeriesViewModel.sno), fileName);
            var db_file_url = "Images/Galeries/Galery_" + galeriesViewModel.sno + "/" + fileName;
            var db_small_image_url = "Images/Galeries/Small/Galery_" + galeriesViewModel.sno + "/" + fileName;

            //exception thrown in this line
            file.SaveAs(path);
            Image smallImage = Image.FromFile(path);
            Size size = new Size();
            size.Height = 128;
            size.Width = 128;
            smallImage = ImageManager.ResizeImage(smallImage, size);
            smallImage.Save(smallImagePath);
            smallImage.Dispose();

            image.ContentType = file.ContentType;
            image.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
            //image.CreateUserId = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
            image.GaleryId = galeriesViewModel.sno;
            image.ImageUrl = db_file_url;
            image.Name = fileName;
            image.UploadSize = file.ContentLength;
            image.SmallImageUrl = db_small_image_url;
            entity.Images.Add(image);
            entity.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
    }



    galeriesViewModel.Galeries = entity.Galeries;
    ViewData["Selected"] = galeriesViewModel.sno;
    return View("ImageOperations", galeriesViewModel);
}
```

I can upload image with this code. But, When I try to add same image consecutivly, again, I get error that is written as title. How can I fix this? What is the reason of this?

**UPDATE**

imageManager Class

```
public static class ImageManager
{
    public static Image ResizeImage(Image imgToResize, Size size)
    {
        int sourceWidth = imgToResize.Width;
        int sourceHeight = imgToResize.Height;

        float nPercent = 0;
        float nPercentW = 0;
        float nPercentH = 0;

        nPercentW = ((float)size.Width / (float)sourceWidth);
        nPercentH = ((float)size.Height / (float)sourceHeight);

        if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
            nPercent = nPercentH;
        else
            nPercent = nPercentW;

        int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
        int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b);
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight);
        g.Dispose();

        return (Image)b;
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: It seems like ImageManager is still using your image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok for me it looks like:
1.You are creating image `Image smallImage = Image.FromFile(path);`
2.You are overriding your reference by new image `smallImage = ImageManager.ResizeImage(smallImage, size);`
3.Your image passed to method `ResizeImage` is still in memory so you have to dispose it in that method before returning new image `b`

```
imgToResize.Dispose();
return (Image)b;
```

Answer (score 3):

Also, when you are finished with the `Image`. Close it. I found this was my problem as I was reading the image after upload to do some processing. The next upload I would get a locked file.

```
Image smallImage = Image.FromFile(path);
//....
smallImage.Dispose();
```

Also, you should wrap your `Graphics g` in a using statement. It will call Dispose when finished or if there is an exception.

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b)
{
    //....
}
//No need to call Dispose() manually.
```

Even better. Ensure your image is disposed of incase of exception. Call `Image.Dispose()` in the `Finally` block.